# Why is the sample mean's variance smaller when we're sampling without replacement?

Tags: variance, sampling, mean, finite-population

I know that we've to use the correction for finite population, but why do we have to use it?

My lecturer said that "Sampling without replacement doesn’t waste information by the chance of finding the same observation twice", but I don't get why do the two things are connected.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, when you sample without replacement, opportunities for a 
variety of outcomes diminish as you begin to 'use up' the population.
This restriction decreases variability.

The distinction between sampling with and without replacement often
results in choosing a binomial distribution (with replacement) or
a hypergeometric distribution (without replacement).

Suppose you are sampling from an urn containing 4 red balls and 8 black balls.
You sample $n = 5$ balls and let $X$ be the number of red balls chosen.

If sampling is with replacement, then $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 5, p = 1/3)$
so that $P(X = k) = {10 \choose k}(1/3)^k(2/3)^{5-k},$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, 5.$ In this case, $E(X) = np = 5(1/3) = 5/3,$ and $Var(X) = np(1-p)
= 5(1/3)(2/3) = 10/9.$

[If we have results $X$ from such a binomial experiment, then
the an unknown $p$ can be estimated by the mean $\hat p = X/n,$ which has $E(\hat p) = p$ and $Var(\hat p) = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}.]$

Below we compare these theoretical values with results from a million 5-draw experiments in R:

```
x = rbinom(10^6, 5, 1/3)
mean(x); 5/3
[1] 1.668055  # aprx E(X) = 5/3
[1] 1.666667  # exact
var(x); 10/9
[1] 1.113681  # aprx Var(X) = 10/9
[1] 1.111111  # exact

hist(x, prob=T, br=(0:6)-.5, col="skyblue2", main="Binomial")
 k = 0:5; pdf=dbinom(k, 5, 1/3)
 points(k, pdf, col="red")
```

Histogram bars show simulated results and red circles show exact binomial
probabilities.

[image]

If sampling is without replacement, then $X$ has a hypergeometric distribution, with
$$P(X = k) = \frac{{4 \choose k}{{8\choose 5 - k}}}{{12 \choose 5}},$$
for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.$ (Notice that $k = 5$ is impossible, because only $4$ red balls are available.

Letting $p = n/T = 4/12 = 1/3,$ we can write
$E(X) = np = 5(1/3) = 5/3,$ the same as for the binomial model above. However,
$$Var(X) =np(1-p)\left[\frac{T-n}{T-1}\right] = 5(1/3)(2/3)[7/11] = 70/99 < 10/9.$$

So the variance is smaller when sampling without replacement. The factor in square brackets is sometimes called the *finite population correction* (because binomial sampling can be regarded as sampling from an infinite population).

```
x = rhyper(10^6, 4, 8, 5)
mean(x); 5/3
[1] 1.667055  # aprx E(X)
[1] 1.666667  # exact
var(x); 70/99
[1] 0.7061733 # aprx Var(X)
[1] 0.7070707 # exact

hist(x, prob=T, br=(0:5)-.5, col="skyblue2", main="Hyergeometric")
 k = 0:4; pdf=dhyper(k, 4, 8, 5)
 points(k, pdf, col="red")
```

[image]